# Truncate a float in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, floating-point

I am using a function to create a list from a float.

```
 float_to_list(0.02).
```

It returns:

```
"2.00000000000000000000e-002"
```

I need it to give me a number exactly like:

"0.20"

If I fed it 5.23

"5.23"

If I fed it 5.5

"5.50"

So basically the number rounded to two decimal places.
Probably an easy fix.

Thanks

EDIT:

I would like to use the io format it looks like it might work,

but it dosen't in this example:

```
wxTextCtrl:setValue( TcGrossProfit, io:format("~p", [NUMBER]), ),
```

seems textctrl wants a string,  I don't want to print it to the screen.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
6> F = 5/2.
2.50000
7> io_lib:format("~.1f",[F]).
["2.5"]
8> io_lib:format("~.2f",[F]).
["2.50"]
9> io_lib:format("~.3f",[F]).
["2.500"]
```

If yes, have a look at the [io_lib](https://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html) module.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer mentioning `io_lib` - the thing that formats to strings (aka lists), instead of just printing the output like `io`.

Comment: @pst Still, the only answer mentioning `io_lib`, as of now.

Answer (score 4):

`mochinum:digits` converts a float to a string with an appropriate level of precision.

```
1> mochinum:digits(1.1).
"1.1"
2> mochinum:digits(1.2345).
"1.2345"
```

Not exactly what the OP requested, but useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could use the function you were already using.

`float_to_list(0.02,[{decimals, 2}])` outputs '0.02'

Or for Elixir users ;)

`:erlang.float_to_list(5.231, decimals: 2)` outputs '5.2'

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://schemecookbook.org/Erlang/NumberRounding) provides functions that truncate/floor or ceil or round a float. Given those you can round to 2 digits by multiplying by 100, rounging and then dividing back by 100 (and possibly rounding again to avoid precision errors)

Answer (score 0):

I know people don't like the, "I am not an expert in language X" answers, but the printf command is quite ubiquitous so I will say, look for an analog of printf in Erlang.

Edit: It looks like the format and fwrite may be those analogs. For more info from [erlang.org](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html).

Answer (score 0):

```erlang
float_to_list_trimmed(Value) ->
    Str = io_lib:format("~.16f", [Value]),
    string:trim(Str, trailing, "0").
```

```
Eshell V13.2.2  (abort with ^G)
1> float_to_list_trimmed(1.23).
"1.23"
```