# TextCtrl -> Truncate a float in Erlang

Tags: floating-point, erlang, new-operator

My last question leads me to this one:

```
wxTextCtrl:setValue( TcGrossProfit, io_lib:format("~.2f",[NewGrossProfit])),
```

generates an error from wxTextCtrl,  with a bad arg.

I know this is the culprit

```
NewGrossProfit = 5.45333,

io_lib:format("~.2f",[NewGrossProfit])
```

Thanks for the last one, hope this one's easier

-B

EDIT

Last Question:
   [Truncate a float in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006201/truncate-a-float-in-erlang)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `io_lib:format("~.2f",[NewGrossProfit])` returns an iolist: `["5.45"]`, but `wxTextCtrl:setValue` seems to need a string (`"5.45"`). So

```
wxTextCtrl:setValue( TcGrossProfit, lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~.2f",[NewGrossProfit])))
```

should work.

Comment: What about if my float is an exponential like: