# Erlang floats and trunc

Tags: erlang, floating-point, truncate

R15b on Windows gives:

```
>trunc(1.9999999999999999999).
2
```

For that matter, just typing the float returns:

```
> 1.9999999999999999999.              
2.0
```

AFAIK, the truncate function should just drop the fractional portion (at least that's what I need, anyway).  A floor function might also do the trick AFAIK, but the floor implementations I've seen posted online use... you guessed it... trunc.

I'm not nitpicking this, I actually need this to be correct for a program I'm developing.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you need numbers to be "correct", don't use floating point.

Comment: Not helpful: 1) This doesn't even attempt to answer my question.  2) In fact, my need for truncate is an attempt to get away from floats and work with straight integers.

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as an answer. Your problem is that an IEEE-compliant floating point implementation can't represent the number 1.9999999999999999999 in binary as anything other than 2.0.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006201/truncate-a-float-in-erlang

Comment: Wooble, THAT is what you should post as an answer.

Comment: @Robert Aloi - thanks, somewhat helpful.  I was hoping to do this with a mathematical truncate, but as last resort can do it with string truncation I guess.

Comment: Try reading http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html or http://floating-point-gui.de/ which tell all.

Comment: Made my eyes glaze over to even look at it.  If I have to know all of that to use floats, I guess I'll avoid them like the plague in the future.

Comment: You should look at either using a ratio or decimal type. A ratio module is fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is decimal numbers are represented as IEEE compliant binary representation (32, 64 or 128 bit).

If you really need precision you should use other numerical data structures as  [Binary Coded Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) or  [fixed-point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a TRUNC to float, maybe this one can help:

```
select substring (convert(varchar(14), CAST (20160303013458 as varchar(14))) , 1 , 8)
```

Comment: The question is specifically about Erlang, not SQL, this is therefore completely unrelated.