# Erlang: using io_lib to convert float to string

Tags: erlang, elixir

I would like to know how can I convert a `Float` to a `String` with two decimal digits using an Erlang library (using the iex)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006681/320615?

Comment: The specific syntax in Elixir would be this: `List.to_string(:io_lib.format("~.2f",[f]))` assuming that `f` is the float you want to convert.